# WebPage works in IE but in a WebBrowser control produces System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, access-violation

I use WebBrowser component and put correct URL it works fine but when I came to another link it produce this exception

> An unhanded Exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional Information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

When I navigate to this URL using IE or Firefox it works fine and there is no error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you happen to have `[unsafe]` anywhere? Hard to see how managed code can produce such error. Anyway please post relevant code maybe you done something wrong.

Comment: frm.url = "C:\..............html";

Comment: Seems similar to this question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915408/error-c-sharp-attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory (There are a bunch of likewise question on SO about your problem ... just search them).

Comment: @ElmozamilElamir try giving real URL, not local file.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow your post and i could see the problem only when page tries to load some registered control withing the WebBrowser object. If the page does not have any control the error does not occur. I could solve the problem quickly by disabling to this EXE only in the DEP exception window.

You can disable DEP (Data Execution Prevention) setting for your application application only at "Advance System Properties > Advanced > Settings > Data Execution Prevention".