# Possible to detect whether an IFRAME is loaded in the Navigating event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, iframe, webbrowser-control

Using the [`WebBrowser` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx), I currently see no way to detect whether a [`Navigating` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating.aspx) is triggered because of the main page's URL is being changed, or whether an IFRAME is loaded.

The `Frame` parameter is always empty, no matter which attributes I put to the IFRAME.

**My question:**

Is there any chance/trick to determine from within a `Navigating` event handler, whether the event was triggered by an IFRAME?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out a workaround:

I had to implement the additional [`DWebBrowserEvents2` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as described in [this Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13598/Extended-NET-2-0-WebBrowser-Control) to get additional events.

Then, I get notified in the [`BeforeNavigate2` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768326%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with more information.

I discovered that `pDisp` is an [`IWebBrowser2` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752127%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and that the [`Parent` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752136%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of that interface is `NULL` for top windows and non-`NULL` for (I)FRAMES.

This was sufficient to me so I could then write:

```
public class BrowserExtendedNavigatingEventArgs : CancelEventArgs
{
    // ...

    public bool IsInsideFrame
    {
        get
        {
            var wb = AutomationObject as UnsafeNativeMethods.IWebBrowser2;
            return wb != null && wb.Parent != null;
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Please note that you have to ensure that you call the `IsInsideFrame` property from the thread that created the web browser control, otherwise you might get access violation exceptions, [just as described here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/324cf907-42f7-4961-af08-68b25baad1fa/access-violation-when-calling-iwebbrowser2navigate?forum=ieextensiondevelopment):

> "...All IE COM objects, including the webbrowser control, are Single
>   Threaded Apartment objects.  Which means, among other things, you can
>   only access them from the thread on which they were created.  If you
>   need to use them from other threads, you need to marshall them using
>   the GIT or CoMarshallInterThreadInterfaceInStream() and related
>   functions..."

I hope this might help others, too.

---

**Alternative solution**

Since [I got `AccessViolationException`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178898/c-sharp-webbrowser-control-system-accessviolationexception) when accessing the `wb.Parent`, although I think I did everything correctly, I was looking for an alternative solution.

I found it in [this Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18935/The-most-complete-C-Webbrowser-wrapper-control).

Basically the article uses an alternative way to determine the frame. It does it by comparing the references to the web browser control.

Pseudo code:

```
public void BeforeNavigate2(
    object pDisp,
    ref object url,
    ref object flags,
    ref object targetFrameName,
    ref object postData,
    ref object headers,
    ref bool cancel)
{
    // ...

    var isTopFrame = _browser._axIWebBrowser2.Equals(pDisp);

    // ...
}
```

My tests run successfully so far, I really do hope that I get no more of these frightening access violation exceptions.